# XML Schema import fails with Request for the permission of type System.Net.WebPermission

Tags: xml, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, xsd

In Visual Studio 2010 SP1, I have an XML Schema (XSD) file open with the following lines:

```
<xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
           schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/03/xml.xsd"/>
```

`xs:import` has a wavy blue line under it, and when you hover over it, you get the following tool tip:

> Request for the permission of type 'System.Net.WebPermission, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

How do I grant this permission so it can download the schema? Thanks.

**Update:**
I forgot to mention this in my original post, but I've already reviewed [Craig Watson's workaround](http://craigwatson1962.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/visual-studio-2010-xml-schema-errorsxsdimport/). It defeats the purpose of having Visual Studio "automatically download DTDs and schemas" (Tools > Options > Text Editor > XML > Miscellaneous). I'm hoping for a solution rather than a workaround. Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

(I know it's an old question. <strike>Since there's no accepted answer,</strike> I've decided to add this one anyway.)

This issue is answered at [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20162279/1531122).

All you need to do is edit the file's properties in Windows Explorer and unblock the downloaded file. That's what's causing the permissions exception: it's a downloaded (and thus untrusted) file.

Comment: Interestingly enough, I also had to unblock the file referencing the other (formerly also blocked) file.

Answer (score 0):

This post covers the workaround: http://craigwatson1962.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/visual-studio-2010-xml-schema-errorsxsdimport/

Not a full solution, since you have to download the XSD, put it in your project, then reference your local copy.