# XML Schema throwing permission failed warning

Tags: xml, visual-studio, schema

I have an xml document and schema and when I open the xml document in visual studio I get a bunch of warnings like:

Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

Does anyone know what might be the cause of these warnings? It is making it difficult to validate the xml document. Also when I hover over the squiggly line under the schemaLocation attribute value, the tool tip gives the error "The schema referenced from this location in your document contains errors"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919470/what-does-unatuthorized-zone-mean-when-browsing-xsd-files-with-visual-studio-20

Comment: I have checked out that post, as well as upvoting it, but the answer provided did not solve my issue, so I figured it was time for a new post about the topic.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did you try starting VS as Administrator? (if you run Windows Vista/7)

Comment: I have tried that and still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is a Visual Studio specific problem. I loaded the xml document in Altova's XMLSpy and it worked just fine.