# Generate sample xml file in VS2013 using reqif.xsd v1.1

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2013, xsd, reqif

I downloaded the latest reqif schema file from http://www.omg.org/spec/ReqIF/20110401/reqif.xsd and loaded the file into visual studio 2013.
Now I'm trying to generate a sample file on the global element and get the following error:
"Imported schema for namespace 'http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace' was not resolved"
I tried unblocking the xsd file as suggested here:
[What does "Unauthorized zone" mean when browsing xsd files with Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919470/what-does-unauthorized-zone-mean-when-browsing-xsd-files-with-visual-studio-20)

I tried changing

```
<xsd:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd"/>
```

to

```
<xsd:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/03/xml.xsd"/>
```

since the location to the xsd seems to be wrong.
I enabled downloading the imported xsd files in visual studio.
Nothing seems to work.

If there's a download for a sample reqif 1.1 file that is based on the schema and uses every single element or a sample generated in visual studio, that would be sufficient though.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find ReqIF1.1 XML schema compliant example files at:
https://hudson.eclipse.org/hudson/job/rmf-nightly/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/test-data/

If they are not enough for you, you could try this:

- download the ReqIF XML schemas from the OMG website

http://www.omg.org/spec/ReqIF/20110401/reqif.xsd

http://www.omg.org/spec/ReqIF/20110402/driver.xsd

- try to set the XML schema location in Visual Studio setting (I have no idea if this is possible)

Comment: thanks. that helps. it's hard to find examples on the topic.